# Logs on personalization

Tags: personalization

Does anyone know whether it`s possible to get from the logs whether Sitecore is rendering a personalized view?
I mean I know we can check the output by looking at the site but wondering whether Sitecore capture it on logs or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not OOTB as far as I know. I just had a quick look at the Sitecore Kernel Assembly.

Normally, the rules need to get triggered when rendering the item. So, I checked the following namespace: `Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors.EvaluateConditions` from the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` and there seems to be no log found in it.

Though, you can have a custom pipeline of the Evaluation of the conditions, that is, you patch the processor

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors.EvaluateConditions, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

Then, you may write up some logs in your custom processor.. An example snippet is shown below

```
public class CustomCondtionEvaluation: EvaluateConditions
{
    protected override void Evaluate(InsertRenderingsArgs args, Item item)
    {
        //Add logs and custom logic if required here            
    }
}
```

Then you have to override the `Run` method which triggers the evaluation of the rule which is at the namespace `Sitecore.Rules.RuleList<T>`. This is where the logs should be written. There are only logs when an error occured